# Google sheets/excel turn column into array and wrap each entry in quotes

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a column of emails and currently am able to turn it into a comma delimited array using.

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(filter(C3:C,C3:C<>"")&", "))
```

How would I wrap each entry in quotes inside this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(char(34)&filter(C3:C,C3:C<>"")&char(34)&", "))
```